# iOS Audio Video custom messages

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am trying to *play* a custom message to a User on iOS.  Just a simple message that will say "Hello World" is all I am wondering. Is there a way to pass a string to `AVFoundation` and have the system play that?  Also, I am looking for an answer in Swift is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVSpeechSynthesizer` can do that:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        speechSynthesizer.speakUtterance(AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello World!"))
    }
}
```